# \xpatchcmd defines macros when applied to undefined commands

Tags: macros, etoolbox, xpatch

I stumbled over this feature (it's part of a bigger question, but I splitted it into two questions):

Say, that we want to use `\xpatchcmd` (from `xpatch`) or `\patchcmd` (from `etoolbox`) and apply those commands (accidentally, for example) on an undefined command sequence, this patching must fail of course.

However, the following code runs and yields `\someundefinedmacro` as `\relax`, where as the `\patchcmd` for `\someotherundefinedmacro` works, but does not return it as `\relax` (it's still undefined)

*I must admit, that one should check this before trying to patch. Or using some `\GenericError` in the fail branch of the patching macros.*

Here a short MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Patching an undefined macro... must fail as patching operation, of course (there's nothing to patch ;-))
\xpatchcmd{\someundefinedmacro}{Ministry of Silly Walks}{Mr. Gumby}{\typeout{Well, this is strange}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition}}

%This does 'nothing'  
\patchcmd{\someotherundefinedmacro}{Ministry of Silly Walks}{Mr. Gumby}{\typeout{Well, this is strange}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition}}


%\show\someundefinedmacro  -> relax
\begin{document}
\someundefinedmacro%  Does nothing, since it's \relax'ed

 % It will fail here (since `\someotherundefinedmacro` is really undefined
\someotherundefinedmacro%  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you are wrong about it happening with the `etoolbox`/`\patchcmd` case. At least, I get an error in that case because the macros are undefined.

Comment: @cfr: Nope, the code runs with frozen TeXLive 2014. There have been some additions to `etoolbox` recently, but I have no idea how relevant this might be

Comment: Do you mean that if you use `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd` in place of `xpatch` and `\xpatchcmd`, you do not get a compilation error with TL 2014? Because I do.

Comment: @cfr: Oh my, I see... one of my d.... typos... I will edit immediately! Thanks. This is even more strange.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour unless a package does something to avoid it, you see the same from the latex test `\@ifundefined{zzz}` which similarly defines `\zzz` to `\relax` (as that is the behaviour of the `\csname` primitive, to define undefined csnames to relax)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But `patchcmd` does not follow this behaviour

Comment: It would please me greatly to blame the author of xpatch:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Let me guess who it can be ... hm... do know you him? ;-)

Comment: A hidden feature. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: An easter-egg?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This warrants a fix, I agree. There should be an initial test whether the macro is defined and the patch should be abandoned otherwise. Note that this is correct in `regexpatchcmd`.

Comment: @egreg:I think, you should transform your comment into an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as part of the processing, the checked macros remained defined as `\relax`; so if

```
\xpatchcmd{\foo}{<search>}{<replace>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

is attempted, `\foo`, `\foo•` (the bullet is for a space), `\\foo` and `\\foo•` remain defined as relax if they weren't to begin with.

This is wrong and will be fixed in the next version of `xpatch`.

The `\foo` macro, however, will remain defined as `\relax` if a patch to an undefined macro is attempted: too much of the package would need to be changed in order to avoid this. A warning will be added in the documentation.

However, patching a macro should generally be preceded by a check that the macro exists and is patchable.

Comment: “A warning will be added in the documentation.”: I don't see it in `xpatch`'s 2020/03/25 release. I stumbled upon this with the MCE: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xpatch}\xapptocmd{\foo}{}{}{}\ifcsdef{foo}{\aaa}{}` (a behavior that I guess was not the case some years ago).