# Patching local commands defined within other macros

Tags: macros, xpatch

This is the follow-up - question, respectively the main cause which led to the (yet) unanswered question here: [\xpatchcmd defines macros when applied to undefined commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239350/xpatchcmd-defines-macros-when-applied-to-undefined-commands)

I tried to patch some command, say, `\someothercommand`, which is defined locally within another macro, say, `\somecommand`, outside of the later macro, e.g. in a preamble.

This fails however. The patching jumps to the *false* branch. I suspect, this is somehow connected to local grouping.

A situation, where this might occur is, when one wants to patch macro definitions which lurk inside of other macros, say in a class or package file.

Consider the case where some **bad** code should be changed without copying the whole outer macro or editing the `.cls` or `.sty` file

Is patching of such locally defined macros possible at all?

I simplified the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{%
  \newcommand{\someothercommand}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{##1}}%
  % This works
  % \xpatchcmd{\someothercommand}{blue}{red}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!!!!}}
  Inside usage: \someothercommand{#1}%
}

% Patching fails 
\xpatchcmd{\someothercommand}{blue}{red}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!!!!}}


\begin{document}
\somecommand{Outer command}

Outside usage: \someothercommand{Inside} but should be \textcolor{red}{Inside}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The colors are just for checking, but there might be more difficult situations, of course

Comment: you can't patch `\someothercommand` before it is defined (how could that work?) don't you just want to patch `\somecommand` to change blue to red?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh, I see... the order is wrong. Changing it works, of course

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't use `\newcommand` inside another command without grouping or you will get an error when you use the outer command more than one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I know, I omitted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look for a suitable place in `\somecommand` to place a hook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{%
  \def\someothercommand##1{\textcolor{blue}{##1}}%
  Inside usage: \someothercommand{#1}%
}


\xpatchcmd{\somecommand}{Inside usage:}{Inside usage: \myspecialsetup}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!!!!}}

\newcommand\myspecialsetup{\renewcommand\someothercommand[1]{\textcolor{red}{##1}}}

\begin{document}
\somecommand{Outer command}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike. Actually I had a similar idea in mind, a wrapper replacing the *bad* code

Answer (score 4):

You can only patch commands that have been defined, so `\somecommand` here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{%
  \newcommand{\someothercommand}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{##1}}%
  % This works
  % \xpatchcmd{\someothercommand}{blue}{red}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!!!!}}
  Inside usage: \someothercommand{#1}%
}

% Patching works 
\xpatchcmd{\somecommand}{blue}{red}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!!!!}}


\begin{document}
\somecommand{Outer command}

Outside usage: \someothercommand{Inside} but should be \textcolor{red}{Inside}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried that already of course. But if there is a really complicated setup inside of `\somecommand`, with multiple occurences of `blue`, this might fail if I want to change only the `blue` inside of `\someothercommand`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but that is always true of  patch, you need to specify enough of the original tokens to locate the right point, the fact that some earlier tokens happen to include `\newcommand` isn't relevant to the patch mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, I just hoped I could bypass the bunch of tokens and patch locally

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can patch the `\someothercommand` after it has been defined (after you have run `\somecommand`) before  `\somecommand` has been run there is nothing to patch. The replacement text of `\somecommand` has been checked for matching `{}` but that is all.